# Is it possible to send images to email addresses using a custom form on Wix, whilst also using sendGrid?

Tags: forms, sendgrid, velo

I'm currently developing a website for someone on Wix and have created a custom user input form with 2 fields, one being for someones name and the other for their email address. The form is used twice on the same page for 2 different events but the difference being they're connected to 2 different datasets.

I have set it up with sendGrid so that when a form is submitted it will send to the email address entered a generic 'Welcome' email but I can only figure out how to send lines of text when I would much rather have an image displayed in the body of the email.

Below is all the code that is used:

email.jsw

```
// Filename: backend/email.jsw (web modules need to have a .jsw extension)

import {sendWithService} from 'backend/sendGrid';

export function sendEmail(subject, body) {
const key = "keygoeshere";
const sender = "emailgoeshere";
const recipient = "emailgoeshere";
return sendWithService(key, sender, recipient, subject, body);
}

export function sendEmailWithRecipient(subject, body, recipient) {
const key = "keygoeshere";
const sender = "emailgoeshere";
return sendWithService(key, sender, recipient, subject, body);
}
```

sendGrid.js

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';  

export function sendWithService(key, sender, recipient, subject, body) {
const url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json";

const headers = {
"Authorization": "Bearer " + key,
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
};

const data = `from=${sender}&to=${recipient}&subject=${subject}&text=${body}`;

const request = {
"method": "post", 
"headers": headers, 
"body": data
};

return fetch(url, request).then(response => response.json());
}
```

Page Code:

```
// For full API documentation, including code examples, visit 
http://wix.to/94BuAAs
import {sendEmail, sendEmailWithRecipient} from 'backend/email';



$w.onReady(function () {
//TODO: write your page related code here...
$w("#dataset1").onAfterSave(sendFormData);
$w("#dataset2").onAfterSave(sendFormData2);
});

export function input1_dblClick(event, $w) {
//Add your code for this event here: 
}

function sendFormData() {
const subject = `New Wild Swimming Request`;
const body = `Hello ${$w("#input1").value}. Thank you for showing interest in Wild Swimming...`;
const recipient = $w("#input2").value;

sendEmailWithRecipient(subject, body, recipient)
.then(response => console.log(response)); 

sendEmail(subject, body)
.then(response => console.log(response));
}

function sendFormData2() {
const subject = `New Plymphony Request`;
const body = `Hello ${$w("#input3").value}. Thank you for showing interest in Plymphony No.1, in Sea!...`;
const recipient = $w("#input4").value;

sendEmailWithRecipient(subject, body, recipient)
.then(response => console.log(response)); 

sendEmail(subject, body)
.then(response => console.log(response));
}
```

I'm having to do it through sendGrid and a custom form as I need 2 separate lists populated for 2 different events, and for whatever reason either Wix doesn't support it or I can't find anything on it but I can't create 2 separate mailing lists and have the 2 forms be sent different emails upon the forms being submitted.

If there is a way to do this by using Wix's own forms then I wuld appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, otherwise any help would be appreciated. Thanks